# htaccess issue - 500 internal error

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have installed an app which has the following rewrite rule. It runs fine in a VPS setup - but in every shared hosting it is showing 500 error. The log is showing "bad delimiter" - I am completely clueless after trying for some time. Please help

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^assets/css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/liinks theme/assets/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/js/(.*) /wp-content/themes/liinks theme/assets/js/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/img/(.*) /wp-content/themes/liinks theme/assets/img/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you change `liinks theme` to `liinks\ theme` ?

Comment: can you confirm/deny?

Comment: While it may not be the exact cause, it sure is a problem. Likely the culprit though, I suggest you post this as an answer.

Comment: @NickW you are right. It was because of the blank space. Thanks again

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not sure that this is the culprit, spaces in  urls need to be treated specially, in this case, escaping the space with a `\`.
Turning

`/wp-content/themes/liinks theme/assets/css/$1`

into

`/wp-content/themes/liinks\ theme/assets/css/$1`

should resolve one possible problem.